# Проверить перегружен ли оператор << для указанного типа

Tags: c++, sfinae

Есть шаблонный класс, который принимает тип данных для хранения. Как проверить, есть ли у принимаемого типа оператор <<?

Нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer
{
public:

    //Если у T перегружен оператор <<, то включить след. метод.
    //какой-то метод.

};
```

Знаю, что есть SFINAE и один раз им пользовался. Делал так:
cделал макрос, который создает "чекер" на метод типа

```
#define CREATE_FUNC_CHECKER(class_name, func_name)\
template <typename _Class>\
class class_name\
{\
    typedef char one;\
    struct two { char x[2]; };\
    template <typename C> static one test(decltype(&C::func_name));\
    template <typename C> static two test(...);\
public:\
    enum { value = sizeof(test<_Class>(0)) == sizeof(char) };\
};

CREATE_FUNC_CHECKER(isHasOperatorStreamOut, operator<<);
```

Потом делал проверку по типу:

```
template<typename C = _ResType_>
        typename std::enable_if<isHasOperatorStreamOut<C>::value, _ResType_*>::type
        load(const std::string& name)
        {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Какой стандарт, С++20?

Comment: Нет, я использую c++17

Comment: Ок. Может просто ничего не делать? Если в методе используется несуществующий <<, а вы его не вызываете, то ошибки не будет (если этот метод - в шаблонном классе, и << применяется к типу, зависящему от шаблонного параметра).

Comment: То есть, просто, перегрузить << для шаблонного класса и не делать проверку? Но если пользователь захочет применить этот оператор, а у T не будет перегрузки, то будет ошибка. Хотелось бы, чтобы нельзя было даже вызвать этот оператор.

Comment: А невозможность вызвать оператор не то же самое, что та ошибка? Только сообщение другое. Разница только в том, можно ли проверить существование уже вашей функции через SFINAE (сейчас нельзя), но раз вы им и не пользуетесь, то наверное без разницы.

Comment: Ну, если сделать, как вы предлагаете, то до тех пор, пока оператор не будет вызван все будет, хорошо, но как только программа подойдет к вызову << - все рухнет. А если сделать проверку, то даже не соберется проект и будет сообщение о том, что оператор не перегружен.

Comment: Нет, при попытке вызвать несуществующий << будет ошибка компиляции. Не ошибка выполнения.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но не правильнее ли будет все таки сделать проверку? Тогда IDE даже до попытки собрать проект сможет сказать, что оператора не существует для данного T.

Comment: Это да. если до завтра никто не напишет ответ, и не забуду, то напишу...

Comment: Понял, спасибо)

Comment: Вообще-то у вас правильно реализовано. Единственное, что надо писать не просто `&C::func_name`, а выбирать требуемую перегрузку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C++20 это делается очень удобно, через `requires`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
  public:
    void foo() requires requires(const T t) {std::cout << t;}
    {
        
    }
};
```

---

В C++17 и раньше нужно писать обычный SFINAE, который выглядит заковыристо. Например так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
  public:
    template <
        typename U = T,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same_v<T, U> &&
            decltype(void(std::cout << std::declval<const U &>()), bool{})(true),
            std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
    >
    void foo()
    {

    }
};
```

Заметьте, функцию пришлось сделать шаблонной, и отдельно проверять, что никто не подсунул неправильный шаблонный параметр.

---

Еще вариант, `static_assert`. Он хорош тем, что можно написать произвольное сообщение об ошибке, но плох тем, что если кто-то попробует проверить существование уже вашего метода с помощью SFINAE, а метод выключен, то он получит ошибку компиляции, и никак не сможет на нее среагировать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsPrintable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsPrintable<T, decltype(void(std::cout << std::declval<const T &>()), void())> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
class Buffer
{
  public:
    void foo()
    {
        static_assert(IsPrintable<T>::value, "This type is not printable.");
    }
};
```

---

Ну и еще вариант, просто ничего не проверять. Поскольку функция - в шаблонном классе, то если ее никто не вызовет, она не будет инстанцирована, и даже если она использует несуществующий `operator<<`, ошибки не будет (если только он вызывается на типе, зависящем от шаблонного параметра).

Минус тот же, что у `static_assert` - попытка вызвать функцию с несуществующим оператором вызовет ошибку компиляции, которую нельзя отловить с помощью SFINAE.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Какой симпатичный - простой и незамысловатый - вопрос, и какой восхитительный ответ! Автору вопроса: Вы можете пометить ответ как "принятый", для этого слева около счетчика голосов есть зеленая галочка. При этом не только автору ответа, но и Вам становится хорошо :-)